# Pandas Date Offset - Groupby, and display value for next week and month

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to add two two columns to a Pandas DataFrame - one which would represent the following weeks value and another which would be the sum of the following 4 weeks.

An example of the existing DataFrame can be seen below. The below DataFrame is only a brief snippet of the entire DataFrame, which spans over a number of years. The DataFrame below was derived using the following function: `df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W'), pd.Grouper('company_name').agg({'returns': 'sum'})`

```html
date         company_name    returns
2014-12-07 Amazon        -0.5
2014-12-14 Amazon        -0.1
2014-12-21 Amazon        0.5
2014-12-28 Amazon        0.3
2015-01-04 Amazon        0.1
2014-12-07 Facebook      0.5
2014-12-14 Facebook      0.5
2014-12-21 Facebook      0.5
2014-12-28 Facebook      -0.5
2015-01-04 Facebook      -0.5
2014-12-07 Google        0.1
2014-12-14 Google        0.1
2014-12-21 Google        0.1
2014-12-28 Google        0.1
2015-01-04 Google        0.1
2014-12-07 Intel         0.2
2014-12-14 Intel         0.2
2014-12-21 Intel         0.2
2014-12-28 Intel         0.2
2015-01-04 Intel         0.2
```

The desired output would return the value for the next week, and the sum of the next 4 weeks starting from 'date' column. An example of the desired output can be seen below.

```html
date         company_name    returns  next_week_return  next_month_return
2014-12-07 Amazon        -0.5        -0.5              0.8
2014-12-14 Amazon        -0.1        0.5               0.8
2014-12-21 Amazon        0.5         0.3               0.8
2014-12-28 Amazon        0.3         0.1               0.8
2015-01-04 Amazon        0.1         0.1               ...           
2014-12-07 Facebook      0.5         0.5               0.0               
2014-12-14 Facebook      0.5         0.5               0.0
2014-12-21 Facebook      0.5         -0.5              0.0
2014-12-28 Facebook      -0.5        -0.5              0.0
2015-01-04 Facebook      -0.5        0.1               ...
2014-12-07 Google        0.1         0.1               0.4
2014-12-14 Google        0.1         0.1               0.4
2014-12-21 Google        0.1         0.1               0.4
2014-12-28 Google        0.1         0.1               0.4
2015-01-04 Google        0.1         0.1               ...
2014-12-07 Intel         0.2         0.2               0.8
2014-12-14 Intel         0.2         0.2               0.8
2014-12-21 Intel         0.2         0.2               0.8
2014-12-28 Intel         0.2         0.2               0.8
2015-01-04 Intel         0.2         0.2
```

An snippet of the original CSV can be seen below.

```html
date CompanyName return
07/12/2014 8x8 Inc -0.0038835
14/12/2014 8x8 Inc 0.036923354
21/12/2014 8x8 Inc 0.108854405
28/12/2014 8x8 Inc 0.042793145
04/01/2015 8x8 Inc -0.027219971
11/01/2015 8x8 Inc -0.038249882
18/01/2015 8x8 Inc 0.045946457
25/01/2015 8x8 Inc -0.107796707
01/02/2015 8x8 Inc -0.056725981
08/02/2015 8x8 Inc 0.024344572
15/02/2015 8x8 Inc 0.00756624
22/02/2015 8x8 Inc -0.04365263
01/03/2015 8x8 Inc -0.02794593
08/03/2015 8x8 Inc -0.039922714
15/03/2015 8x8 Inc 0.020848566
22/03/2015 8x8 Inc 0.116712617
29/03/2015 8x8 Inc 0.028952565
05/04/2015 8x8 Inc 0.053253322
12/04/2015 8x8 Inc -0.006787356
19/04/2015 8x8 Inc -0.00912207
26/04/2015 8x8 Inc 0.013652089
03/05/2015 8x8 Inc -0.021702736
10/05/2015 8x8 Inc -0.021004273
17/05/2015 8x8 Inc 0.012888286
24/05/2015 8x8 Inc -0.021177262
31/05/2015 8x8 Inc -0.027630051
07/12/2014 AB SA -1.015859196
14/12/2014 AB SA -0.01810143
21/12/2014 AB SA -0.073869849
28/12/2014 AB SA 0.000666445
04/01/2015 AB SA 0.051293294
11/01/2015 AB SA 0.004735605
18/01/2015 AB SA 0.014073727
25/01/2015 AB SA 0.097002705
01/02/2015 AB SA 0.00337648
08/02/2015 AB SA 0.018093743
15/02/2015 AB SA 0.019667392
22/02/2015 AB SA 0.024844339
01/03/2015 AB SA 0.015707129
08/03/2015 AB SA 0.109611209
15/03/2015 AB SA -0.039164849
22/03/2015 AB SA -0.002909093
29/03/2015 AB SA 0.007256926
05/04/2015 AB SA -0.025385791
12/04/2015 AB SA 0.019584469
19/04/2015 AB SA -0.01342302
26/04/2015 AB SA 0.073405725
03/05/2015 AB SA -0.018666287
10/05/2015 AB SA 0.019350984
17/05/2015 AB SA -0.030814439
24/05/2015 AB SA 0.027386256
31/05/2015 AB SA -0.033285978
07/12/2014 ACCO Brands Corp 0.432332004
14/12/2014 ACCO Brands Corp -0.064822249
21/12/2014 ACCO Brands Corp 0.010163837
28/12/2014 ACCO Brands Corp 0.022223137
04/01/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.034659702
11/01/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.026514522
18/01/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.018868484
25/01/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.013010237
01/02/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.071850737
08/02/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.00126183
15/02/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.016000601
22/02/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.01420295
01/03/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.010457612
08/03/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.006591982
15/03/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.008257798
22/03/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.039272062
29/03/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.035312622
05/04/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.012315427
12/04/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.037241541
19/04/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.025075941
26/04/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.010535083
03/05/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.044016885
10/05/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.013845407
17/05/2015 ACCO Brands Corp 0.005056901
24/05/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.024251348
31/05/2015 ACCO Brands Corp -0.051701374
07/12/2014 Acer Inc 3.829777429
07/12/2014 Acer Inc -3.46435286
14/12/2014 Acer Inc 0.042160811
14/12/2014 Acer Inc 0.021342273
21/12/2014 Acer Inc -0.056618894
21/12/2014 Acer Inc -0.046304568
28/12/2014 Acer Inc 0.033415997
28/12/2014 Acer Inc 0.062759689
04/01/2015 Acer Inc 0.002344667
04/01/2015 Acer Inc -0.004460974
11/01/2015 Acer Inc 0.082988363
11/01/2015 Acer Inc 0.093933758
18/01/2015 Acer Inc -0.033983853
18/01/2015 Acer Inc -0.042689409
25/01/2015 Acer Inc 0.017136282
25/01/2015 Acer Inc -0.012539349
01/02/2015 Acer Inc 0.002424244
01/02/2015 Acer Inc 0.010980502
08/02/2015 Acer Inc -0.014634408
08/02/2015 Acer Inc -0.015723594
15/02/2015 Acer Inc -0.014851758
15/02/2015 Acer Inc 0.025040432
22/02/2015 Acer Inc 0
22/02/2015 Acer Inc 0.022919261
01/03/2015 Acer Inc 0.024631787
01/03/2015 Acer Inc -0.007581537
08/03/2015 Acer Inc 0.05445132
08/03/2015 Acer Inc 0.027028672
15/03/2015 Acer Inc -0.023311079
15/03/2015 Acer Inc -0.022472856
22/03/2015 Acer Inc -0.002361276
22/03/2015 Acer Inc 0
29/03/2015 Acer Inc -0.021506205
29/03/2015 Acer Inc 0.012048339
05/04/2015 Acer Inc -0.021978907
05/04/2015 Acer Inc -0.028109292
12/04/2015 Acer Inc -0.004950505
12/04/2015 Acer Inc 0.02756683
19/04/2015 Acer Inc -0.007472015
19/04/2015 Acer Inc 0.003016594
26/04/2015 Acer Inc 0.009950331
26/04/2015 Acer Inc 0.006006024
03/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.004962789
03/05/2015 Acer Inc 0.002989539
10/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.040614719
10/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.087282784
17/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.064193158
17/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.072605718
24/05/2015 Acer Inc 0.008253142
24/05/2015 Acer Inc -0.032031208
31/05/2015 Acer Inc 0.005464494
31/05/2015 Acer Inc 0.057961788
```

From the above I would hope to add two columns to each row - one `next_week_return`, where the following weeks return for the specific companies are shown; and another: `next_month_return`, which would be the sum of the following four weeks return.

Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a few example lines from `df` before the aggregation?

Comment: I'm simply reading from a CSV using: `df = pd.read_csv`. Then I convert the `date` to datetime `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`. This produces daily information per company. I then aggregate using the following function: `df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='W'), pd.Grouper('company_name').agg({'returns': 'sum'})`.  I hope that helps

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. It would be super helpful to get a sample of actual data that we could easily copy-paste into a python shell and start experimenting on.

Comment: Is it possible to add a the file to a question? I'm afraid I don't see that option.

Comment: No need to add the entire file (though you can edit in a link to a Google Drive folder, Dropbox file, GitHub gist, etc.). All we need is a copy-pastable sample of a few lines from the file, just enough that you can specify the exact output you expect given that small input.

Comment: So you'd need a sample copy and paste from the original CSV? Apologies for all the questions.

Comment: Yup, what is useful here is a big enough & varied enough sample from the original CSV (might be 5 lines or 30) for which (1) you can manually specify the expected output, and (2) your existing code runs on the sample, but does not produce the expected output.

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler. Thanks very much. I added some data to the the question, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your example snippet of the input CSV, one solution is to write a custom function to use with `df.apply()` that accepts a sub-DataFrame for each company, and for each date in the sub-DataFrame, computes the sum of `return` over the specified number of lookahead days.

The following code assumes that `df` holds your sample data from the original CSV.

```
# Convert string dates to pandas.Timestamp 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Within each CompanyName, sort by date, because we'll
# set the date column as a DatetimeIndex and will
# index-slice it with pandas date offsets, and this
# requires a sorted index.
df.sort_values(['CompanyName', 'date'], inplace=True)

# Set a MultiIndex to ensure that the calculated
# columns returned by the custom function align correctly
df.set_index(['CompanyName', 'date'], inplace=True)    

# Define a custom function to sum the values of `return` for 
# each CompanyName sub-DataFrame. The defaults of 1 and 1+28
# capture the month (defined to be 28 days) immediately following
# each date, excluding the date itself. To get just the 
# next week's values, use start=1, end=7.
def sum_return_over_next_i_to_j_days(df, first=1, last=1+28):
    day = pd.offsets.Day(1)
    df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True, inplace=True)
    rets = [df.loc[today + first*day : today + last*day, 'return'].sum(min_count=1) 
            for today in df.index]
    return pd.DataFrame(rets, 
                        index=df.index, 
                        columns=[f'sum_return_next_{first}-{last}_days'])

# Apply the above function to input CSV
df['next_week_return'] = df.groupby('CompanyName').apply(sum_return_over_next_i_to_j_days, 1, 7)
df['next_month_return'] = df.groupby('CompanyName').apply(sum_return_over_next_i_to_j_days, 1, 1+28)

df = df.reset_index()

# Print result
df.head(10)
  CompanyName       date    return  next_week_return  next_month_return
0     8x8 Inc 2014-07-12 -0.003883               NaN                NaN
1     8x8 Inc 2014-12-14  0.036923          0.108854           0.066976
2     8x8 Inc 2014-12-21  0.108854          0.042793           0.004068
3     8x8 Inc 2014-12-28  0.042793         -0.084672          -0.146522
4     8x8 Inc 2015-01-02 -0.056726         -0.027946          -0.089796
5     8x8 Inc 2015-01-03 -0.027946               NaN          -0.061850
6     8x8 Inc 2015-01-18  0.045946         -0.107797          -0.100230
7     8x8 Inc 2015-01-25 -0.107797               NaN          -0.036086
8     8x8 Inc 2015-02-15  0.007566         -0.043653          -0.044507
9     8x8 Inc 2015-02-22 -0.043653               NaN           0.115858

df.tail(10)
    CompanyName       date    return  next_week_return  next_month_return
120    Acer Inc 2015-08-02 -0.014634           0.08148           0.081480
121    Acer Inc 2015-08-02 -0.015724           0.08148           0.081480
122    Acer Inc 2015-08-03  0.054451               NaN                NaN
123    Acer Inc 2015-08-03  0.027029               NaN                NaN
124    Acer Inc 2015-10-05 -0.040615               NaN           0.176922
125    Acer Inc 2015-10-05 -0.087283               NaN           0.176922
126    Acer Inc 2015-11-01  0.082988               NaN                NaN
127    Acer Inc 2015-11-01  0.093934               NaN                NaN
128    Acer Inc 2015-12-04 -0.004951               NaN                NaN
129    Acer Inc 2015-12-04  0.027567               NaN                NaN
```